# rails create log file daily

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I'm trying to create log files daily. 
Here's the code I'm using:

```
  config.logger = Logger.new("log/dev_daily_#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')}.log", 'daily')
```

Now the problem with this is that whenever I run my rake task it creates a new log file. This there any way to skip this?

Also, is there any other way of doing this(may be a gem)?

Comment: Get rid of hms part of time: `config.logger = Logger.new("log/dev_daily_#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}.log", 'daily')`.

Comment: @mudasobwa What if it overides the logs file? I don't want that  to happen. I think we need to use the older file if it already exists.

Comment: What if you go and give it a try, huh? It will append, not overwrite, as clearly stated in a documentation.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks a lot its working fine :)